# Get out of stock product collection in magento2

Tags: product, magento2.2, php-7, out-of-stock

I want to get the wishlist collection for the customer.

```
$this->wishlist->create()->loadByCustomerId($this->session->create()->getCustomerId(), true)->getItemCollection();
```

How to add out of stock products with this collection whether the display out of stock product configuration is enabled or not.

Comment: If you can see your collection data it's already returned out of stock product.

Comment: Its returns collection based upon the display out of stock admin configuration

Comment: No, I am not enable out stock product enable setting still above collection display out of stock product.

Comment: No. ...........